# Why am I getting a 0 at the beginning of my output, I'm not seeing anything that would cause this?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I keep getting a 0 at the beginning of my output and can't figure out exactly what I'm doing wrong that is causing this. If anyone has suggestions please let me know. Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Load the dataset into a pandas DataFrame
internet = pd.read_csv('internetusage.csv')

# Extract the columns we're interested in
y = internet['internet_usage']
x = internet['bachelors_degree']

# Add a constant term to the input array
x = sm.add_constant(x)

# Create the SLR model using the OLS method
model = sm.OLS(y, x).fit()

# Use the model.predict() method to find the predicted value for a given input
bach_percent = float(input())

prediction = model.predict([1,bach_percent])

print(pd.DataFrame(prediction))
print('dtype:', internet['internet_usage'].dtypes)
```

Output:

```
           0
0  61.865155
dtype: float64
```

Expected Output:

```
0  61.865155
dtype: float64
```

When I just print prediction it displays like this:

```
[61.86515455]
dtype: float64
```

Which is not what is expected.

Comment: That's the column header.

Comment: Why not print out just `prediction`? Why convert it to a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: I see you added the printout of just `prediction`. Is there an issue with it being an array or list (I didn't run the code so I don't know which it is)? If so, just extract that single value: `print(prediction[0])`.

Comment: @jared With my class I'm taking they don't want the output as an array for it to be correct unfortunately

Comment: So why can't you do the indexing I suggest in my last comment?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jared Hey thanks for the help I just got it. I did indexing and rounded it.